# Spring RestTemplate - passing in batches of GET requests

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I need to query a server for links that can be obtained by giving the server a reference.

Lets say I have 10 references and I want to get 10 links back all in one go in an arrayList.

Is the below the most efficient way to do it? It looks pretty resource intensive and takes approximately 4672ms to generate

I looked at the docs for RestTemplate: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#getForEntity-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.util.Map- but there doesn't seem to be an easier way to do what I want to do.

```
ArrayList<String> references = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<>();
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); 
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ResponseEntity<String> resource = restTemplate.getForEntity(references.get(i), String.class);
    links.add(resource.getBody().toString());
}
```

EDIT:

Based on suggestions, I have changed my code to but I'm getting an error: "Asynchronous execution requires an AsyncTaskExecutor to be set":

```
ArrayList<String> references = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<>();
AsyncRestTemplate asyncRestTemplate = new AsyncRestTemplate(new CustomClientHttpRequestFactory()); 
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Future<ResponseEntity<String>> resource = asyncRestTemplate.getForEntity(references.get(i), String.class);
    ResponseEntity<String> entity = resource.get(); //this should start up 10 threads to get the links asynchronously
    links.add(entity.getBody().toString());
}
```

I looked at the reference docs but none of the constructors allow for me to set both a AsyncListenableTaskExecutor and a ClientHttpRequestFactory (the ClientHttpRequestFactory I used - CustomClientHttpRequestFactory just extends SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory so that I can get redirect links successfully: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/AsyncRestTemplate.html#AsyncRestTemplate--

Comment: You can use an `Iterator` instead of `references.get(i)`. You don't need to call `.toString()` on the response body, it's already a `String`. Consider asking this on codereview.

Comment: You don't need to add the `StringHttpMessageConverter` every time. Once is enough, though note that one should already have been registered by default.

Comment: You also don't need to create a new `RestTemplate` every loop iteration. Once is enough.

Comment: Thanks - but I'm still calling the server 10 times to get back 10 links. Is there something more efficient I can do?

Comment: Unless your server supports a batching API, no.

Comment: OK. I guess then it would be a server constraint. I edited my code according to your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: You can put your solution regarding the server supporting a batching API as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you're making those REST calls sequentially - i.e. nothing is done in parallel.

You could use [the asynchronous variant of RestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-async-resttemplate) and make those calls in parallel.

Comment: Thanks - i think your answer was the best one and hence I marked it correct. I do however noticed that if I used the async version of the resttemplate, the rest request takes longer to return then the sync version which is weird...i will post a new question on it shortly.

Comment: See new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572475/spring-resttemplate-async-vs-sync-resttemplate

Comment: the link is down