# Aggregate multiple rest calls spring boot 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming

I'm new in reactive programming in java and I'm trying to make an microservice that aggregate calls from 3 other microservices.

I can't figure out how to handle this 3 rest calls in asynchronous way and then aggregate the result. I have a simple business all the three methods returns boolean and I want to make an or on them.

Can I do this in Java with Spring boot 2?

Thanks

Comment: if you want to call the other microservices, take a look at RestTemplate of spring boot

Comment: I'm using feign,  but I can change. It's a way to call with RestTemplate asynchronous ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572475/spring-resttemplate-async-vs-sync-resttemplate. there is AsyncRestTemplate

Comment: Thanks for your response, I can't figure out how to use with Spring boot 2 and I think that can be a simple way

Comment: I think using spring boot would be more convenient than using a http client and a response serializer. You could start with https://start.spring.io/

Comment: A configure a reactive project, but I have problem when I need to aggregate calls. If you cand give me an example. Thanks